# A device or a method for comparing original and transferred video

Tags: video, video-quality, software, hardware, electronics

I want to compare a video that is transfered through a Device and the original video by connecting them to a monitor or to a device that can measure everything for me and give us a full complete list of the differences so we can know how to improve our device in a way that give us the same result as the Original Video, and if you have any other methods to do so it would be really helpful and appreciated.